# UIDatePicker opening in incorrect orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I am creating an iOS app with objective -c.

I am using two `UIViewController`

1. newviewController (portrait).
2. editviewController (landscape).

   newUIViewController
   -> textbox (datePicker)
   -> button
    first time open to datePicker portrait.

   [image]

   editviewcontroller
   -> `UITableView`
   -> `UIButton` (Add row,save,cancel)
   -> `UITableView` each row delete button.
   first add row and then click to delete row and cancel button click to newuiviewcontroller show datepicker rotate? see my sample pic

   ```
   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
      return  YES;
    }

    - (NSUInteger ) supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
    }

     - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
   how to solve this problems?
   ```

Comment: in which screen you open datePicker?

Comment: portrait screen open datepicker